# Error when adding form control to <mat-select>

Tags: angular

I'm trying to add form control to the `<mat-select>`'s in my project, but I keep on getting this error `ng: No provider for ngControl`

This occurs when I add the `[formControl]="formControlName"` property to my mat-select. It doesn't seem to recognize the property. I'm following the example from the material.angular.io website.

My angular version is up to date with their website being 5.2.8 and material version 5.2.4

If anyone has experience with this, please let me know. Thank you.

```
  <mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Choose one" [formControl]="formControlName" [errorStateMatcher]="matcher">
    <mat-option>Clear</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="valid">Valid option</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="invalid">Invalid option</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
  <mat-hint>Errors appear instantly!</mat-hint>
  <mat-error *ngIf="selected.hasError('required')">You must make a selection</mat-error>
  <mat-error *ngIf="selected.hasError('pattern') && !selected.hasError('required')">
    Your selection is invalid
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Can you please show the container module imports.

Comment: have you correctly imported your angular material component in your app-module ?

Comment: @Fjordo yes, all my other components work just fine. The main ones here are MatFormFieldModule, MatSelectModule, and MatInputModule I believe, and I have all those imported. Everything else works fine for the select component, except that form control.

Comment: Will you show the code for the related form in your component? It looks like to me you're missing the [formGroup]="yourFormGroupName" on your mat-form-field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally was able to find a solution: In your main module, you need to import `ReactiveFormsModule`

Answer (score 0):

I used almost the same in one of my application ..and its working..Hope this will help you,

HTML:

```
                <form [formGroup]="clienteForm" novalidate>
                <div class="row">    
                    <div class="col-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-xl-3">       
                        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                        <mat-select class="example-full-width" #accionSelecionada [formControl]="clienteForm.controls['accionSelecionada']" [(ngModel)]="tipoAccion"
                            name="accionSelecionada" placeholder="Seleccione una acción:" required>
                            <mat-option *ngFor="let accion of acciones" [value]="accion.valor"> {{accion.accion}} </mat-option>
                        </mat-select>
                        </mat-form-field>    
                    </div>        
                </div>
            </form>
```

TypeScript:

```
            export class ABCComponent implements OnInit {


                    clienteForm: FormGroup;


                    constructor() {

                        this.clienteForm = this.constructoclienteForm.group({

                                accionSelecionada: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])]

                        });
                    }

                acciones: any = [{
                    'accion': 'Activar',
                    'valor': 'D'
                    }, {
                    'accion': 'Desactivar',
                    'valor': 'B'
                    }];
            }
```